# Group by/aggregate error - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, aggregate

The SQL I am using for this query is as follows:

```
SELECT p.publisherID, p.publisherName, month(o.orderDate), sum(ol.quantity)
FROM Orders o, orderLine ol, Publisher p, Book b
WHERE ol.orderNum = o.orderNum
And ol.isbn is not null
And b.isbn=ol.isbn
And p.publisherID=b.publisherID
Group By p.publisherID, p.publisherName;
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Orders.orderDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Now as you can see, the orderDate column is in fact in a function, but why would I still get this error? The only thing I can think of is that the month() function shows (expression datetime) when I hover over it, and the orderDate is just a "date" datatype. I dunno if that is the problem.

Comment: it is in a function but not an aggregate function, so instead of returning 01/01/2017 you are returning january, however you could still have the same publisher with another order month. you still need to group each month together etc just add the month(orderdate) to your group by. If you don't want a row for each month and publisher then you'd be better off dropping it from the select entirely.

Comment: The month function is NOT an aggregate function.  Example of aggregate functions are Avg, Count, Max, Min, Sum, etc...  Aggregate functions operate over multiple rows.  The month function only operates on a single row.

Comment: when you use group by, only aggregate functions are allowed on columns  which are not in group by

Comment: What output do you actually want here?  Can you show us a small representative sample?

Comment: General comment: Don't put commas in the `FROM` clause, but use explicit joins if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.publisherID, p.publisherName, month(o.orderDate), sum(ol.quantity)
FROM Orders o, orderLine ol, Publisher p, Book b
WHERE ol.orderNum = o.orderNum
And ol.isbn is not null
And b.isbn=ol.isbn
And p.publisherID=b.publisherID
Group By p.publisherID, p.publisherName, month(o.orderDate);
```

This would return

```
+-----+------+-------+-------+
| 1   |Bookco|January| 12    |
| 1   |Bookco|Febuary| 6     |
| 2   |NextBk|January| 2     |
+-----+------+-------+-------+
```

Without the order date in the group by the compiler doesn't know how to handle a variety of months coming out for each publisher.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Rules for Group BY Clause:

1. Only items allowed in the select list of query with group by clause are,

   - Expressions in Group BY
   - Aggregate Functions (SUM, COUNT, MAX, Min, AVG)
2. Expressions in the group by clause need not to be included in select statement

As already explained by others, Month is not an aggregate function but a scalar one.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you have to add `Orders.orderDate` in Group By list.

Comment: This would make the error go away, and it might even be what the OP intended, but we don't know this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you got confused with simple scalar function and [aggregate function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function). Aggregate function takes a set of arguments(field values from many rows) and produce one result, while simple scalar function produce result for each argument it takes. In your case, for a set

```
orderDate      quantity 
01/01/2017     2        
02/01/2017     2
03/01/2017     2

SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM table
```

Will produce only one value - 6. While

```
SELECT MONTH(orderDate) FROM table
```

Will produce three rows of values:

```
1
2
3
```

That's the difference between simple scalar and aggregate functions: aggregate functions can change number of rows in the result, while for simple function there will be equal number of rows in the input and output of the function.
Thus, you cannot recieve one result per group of rows, as you do for aggregate function, so you must add field with simple function to GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Month is not an aggregate function, you need to include this column in your group by clause:

```
SELECT p.publisherID, p.publisherName, month(o.orderDate), sum(ol.quantity)
FROM Orders o, orderLine ol, Publisher p, Book b
WHERE ol.orderNum = o.orderNum
And ol.isbn is not null
And b.isbn=ol.isbn
And p.publisherID=b.publisherID
Group By p.publisherID, p.publisherName, month(o.orderDate);
```